# Is asking for a bounded time complexity allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Say, if someone asks for a code-golf like this:

> ## Test primality under polynomial time
>
> Given a positive integer, test whether it is prime.
>
> ### Rules
>
> - The algorithm must have polynomial time complexity in respect to the number of digits of the input.
> - The algorithm must be deterministic.
> - Input type and format doesn't matter, but it must be able to represent arbitrary-length integers. In Haskell. `Integer` is an example. In C++, since it doesn't natively support arbitrary-length integers, `std::string` with ASCII digits would be acceptable.
> - If the input isn't a positive integer, it falls in *don't care* situation.

This will force everyone to implement AKS Primality Test, if their language doesn't have a builtin for it. Can such thing be accepted?

Comment: Yup, check out the restricted complexity tag: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity

Comment: Just as a note, be careful when doing this - you'll likely get some invalid submissions. Further, you might not get many solutions, since answers will essentially have to prove they meet the requirement. I think most users will tend to implement a known algorithm rather than do something original. None of that makes this bad - just some stuff I think is worth knowing.

Comment: The AKS algorithm is not particularly hard to implement - the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) makes it look very doable. I think the hard part was the proof of its optimality, not the implementation.